# Retrieve names of all sites on a webserver

Tags: iis, web-server

Is there anyway that I could get names of all sites hosted on a IIS web server, to a text file?

Any command or any alternative?

Tried googling but couldnt find anything related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Powershell` and the `get-website` Cmdlet :

```
get-website >c:\my\file.txt
```

Or for Name only :

```
get-website | select name >c:\my\file.txt
```

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh867835.aspx

---

**Edit :**

For Windows Server 2003 and IIS 6 you can use `iisweb.vbs` utility.

From a DOS `CMD` prompt run :

```
iisweb /query >c:\my\file.txt
```

Or

```
cscript c:\windows\system32\iisweb.vbs /query >c:\my\file.txt
```

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739153(v=ws.10).aspx
- https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/69a90de9-1492-45b2-853e-1e7457f309db.mspx

Comment: It just created a file in the specified folder..no contents..:(

and fyi..my web server has iis 6

Comment: @Vysakh It requires to be run as an Administrator

Comment: already an administrator

Comment: Do you run it on the IIS Server itself ?

Comment: also throwing error get-website is not a cmdlet, function etc...

Comment: yes for sure...server 2003

Comment: @Vysakh What is your OS ??

Comment: Server 2003 Windows and IIS 6

Comment: @Vysakh Edited for 2003 and IIS6

Comment: Is this too powershell?

Comment: @Vysakh No, it runs at DOS cmd prompt, it is a VBS script

Answer (score 1):

You may try :

```
httpd -S 2>&1 > /my/file.txt
```

Comment: I am not using an Apache web server..Using IIS